# Which query has better performance - where clause with case statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Cars is a table that has a column CarType. CarType is non-null and can contain 2 values. CarDonated and CarSold.

We pass in a parameter from a report to include either all CarTypes, or a specific CarType (such as CarDonated).

The parameter in scenario 1 passes in either 'Car' (for all CarTypes), 'CarD' for CarDonated, 'CarS' for CarSold.

```
select *
from Cars c
where c.CarType like @CarTypeParam + '%'
```

OR

The parameter in scenario 2 passes in '0' (for all CarTypes), 'CarDonated', 'CarSold'

```
select *
from Cars c
where c.CarType = case when @CarTypeParam = '0' 
                   then c.CarType
                   else @CarTypeParam 
                  end
```

Which scenario/coding method is better? I'm not too familiar with using case statements in where clauses. Is the optimizer still able to use index on the CarType in both scenarios? Which is better coded?

SQL Server 2008 R2 (along with SSRS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is potentially slightly better as `CarType like @CarTypeParam + '%'` can at least do a range seek on an index on `CarType` whereas the `CASE` expression is entirely unsargable.

With only 50% selectivity an index is unlikely to be used anyway though unless you happen to have one with leading column `CarType` that covers all the columns in the query.

Comment: Currently the CASE also wont work as it tests the equality of c.CarType + '%' rather than using a LIKE

Comment: @AlexK. , oops, that was a typo. Should just be "c.CarType". Fixed.

Comment: @MartinSmith , if there was no index on CarType, would there be much difference in performance between the two?

Comment: Both would end up doing a full scan so difference would just be CPU. I don't know if one would be any better than the other but hopefully as this is for a report you won't be processing anywhere near enough rows for it to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Gabe - the best way to determine this is to test it for yourself. Look at the query plan generated for both and make sure, at least, both queries are doing seeks instead of scans. Then, I would run these queries while monitoring the server with Profiler, to check the number of reads each is doing, and which might be using more overall resources. This is sound advice for any queries you are writing.